# logically equivalent to the statement $\lnot (\lnot p \land \lnot q) \lor \lnot (p \lor q)$

Tags: logic

Is this equal to 1? and why? I get that $ \lnot(\lnot p\lor \lnot q)$  would just mean $p \land q$ and $\lnot(p \lor q)$ would mean $\lnot p \land \lnot q$.

I do not get the rest.

Comment: But $\lnot(\lnot p\land \lnot q)\lor(p\lor q)$ is not always true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering $\lnot(\lnot p \land \lnot q) \lor \lnot(p \lor q)$, note that the left formula by de Morgan and double negation equals

$$\lnot(\lnot p \land \lnot q) \equiv p \lor q$$

and so your formula is essentially of the form $\phi \lor \lnot \phi$ which is true ($1$) in classical logic as the law of the excluded middle.

Comment: Why do you get $\phi \lor \lnot \phi$ and not $\phi \lor \phi$? There may be a typo in your first line

Comment: Use $\phi = p \lor q$. The OP edited the question after my answer.

Comment: Yes, if you copy the problem correctly you get $\phi \lor \phi$, but you made a typo

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you mean equal to one. The statement you have is an example of a tautology. That means that the proposition is true for every assignment of truth values to its components. You can see this by distributing the first negation like this:
$$\\$$By de Morgan's law:
$$\neg(\neg  p \land \neg q)\equiv \neg (\neg p)\lor \neg (\neg q)\equiv (p\lor q)$$ 
$$\\$$Then,
 $$\neg(\neg  p \land \neg q) \ \lor \neg(p\lor q)\equiv (p\lor q)\lor \neg (p\lor q)$$
$$\\$$Basically you have a proposition in the form of $(A\lor \neg A)$, where $A$ is $(p\lor q)$. This is what we call a tautology because it's like the statement "Either the sky is blue or it is not". It  always will  be true.